# How to stop @font-face from capitalizing letters

Tags: css, font-face

I'm usind `face-face` css in my stylesheet, but the only problem is that it is capitalizing all "i" on the site. Can anyone tell me whats wrong.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Arial Black";
src: url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.eot');
src: url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.eot?') format('opentype'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.svg#Arial Black') format('svg');

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `i` and `I` look different in font-face?

Comment: Yes I am sure, without the font face Everything is good but with the font-face all "i" are capital "I"

Comment: can you recreate the problem in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please specify which actual font you are using (i.e. where did you get the font from) and provide a testable demo of the issue. It sounds like you are using a broken font.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Arial Black";
src: url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.eot');
src: url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.eot?') format('opentype'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/wp-content/themes/RatedRnB/fonts/ariblk-webfont.svg#Arial Black') format('svg');
text-transform:none;
font-style:normal;

}
```

Comment: And how would you target all `i`s

Comment: `text-transform` isn’t a valid [font property descriptor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop-desc).